# How can I split registered COCO dataset to train and validation for Detectron2?

Tags: pytorch, dataset, detectron

I'm trying to train an instance segmentation model using Detectron2 but I'm not sure how I could validate every certain number of iterations on 20% of the data available.

I have multiple registered COCO datasets using `register_coco_instances()` but I would like to split them into training and validation datasets.

For example, I have `(dataset_1, dataset_2, dataset_3,)` that I want to split 80/20 to become training and validation as such:

```
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = (dataset_1_train, dataset_2_train, dataset_3_train,)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = (dataset_1_val, dataset_2_val, dataset_3_val,)
```

And I would like it to validate on all the validation datasets every certain number of iterations. I would probably need a custom trainer for this but I couldn't find a way to split the datasets nor validate on all of the available validation datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer a portion of your question.
1 - To Validate your model during training and to check if its over or underfitting you would need to add a "hook". I just used the code from : https://eidos-ai.medium.com/training-on-detectron2-with-a-validation-set-and-plot-loss-on-it-to-avoid-overfitting-6449418fbf4e

2 - Sorry, I'm not too sure about loading a list of datasets. Maybe
`cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("val_1", "val_2", ...)`
will work